# How to retrieve a file from Bitlocker enabled HardDrive?

Tags: windows-server-2008, bitlocker

How to retrieve a file from Bitlocker enabled HardDrive ?

We have 400 GB of Image files which we want to encrypt our Hard Drive for data protection.

We are exploring Bitlocker on our Windows 2008 Server. My question is, on enabling the bitlocker, whether the files are encrypted by itself ? How to retrieve a file from the Hard drive which has Bit locker enabled?

Comment: What have you researched?  what have you tried?

Comment: Just exploring a bit of Bitlocker and EFS - Encrypting File System. I prefer to go for Bitlocker. Still need to know a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BitLocker works on a volume-level - the entire underlying partition will be encrypted, block-by-block, using a so-called Volume Encryption Key.

When the Operating System boots (or when the volume is mounted), the Volume Encryption Key (optionally encrypted by a PIN code, a TPM-stored key or both in combination) is loaded into memory, and from there, **access to the entire file system is totally transparent to the user** - you don't have to *do anything* to decrypt the files.

Comment: So simple as copying a file from External Drive and moving to the Bitlocker enabled Hard Drive and fetching the file from Bitlocker Enabled Hard Drive to an External Drive

Comment: @goofyui Yes, as long as it's mounted on the same system, if you move the disk, you'll need the recovery key to unlock it on another computer (again, subject to policy and initial configuration)